# How to convert English to Hindi using jquery in localhost (Without Internet) in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In my web application (which run in localhost) I need to convert text English to Hindi language. It's very simple using [JSAPI](http://google.com/jsapi) . But it always required Internet connection.

I tried using copy the code and put inside my project but it still required internet connection.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: *but it still required internet connection* - surely, since at least it uses dictionary at server side. Well, if you have some English -> Hindi dictionary available at your localhost - you can try to create your own translator using it.

Comment: jQuery is unlikely to help, I think you mean JavaScript but I don't think this will help either as the translation will be done on Google's servers. Just translating word for word is unlikely to work as each language's structure is likely to be different